# Multidimensional obstacle avoidance in ODE (Visualization)

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems

A simple 3-dimensional ODE system is given:

$F=\begin{cases} \dot{x}=g+g_{U_{rep}} \\ \dot{g}=-g+\frac{df}{dx} \\ \dot{h}=-h+\frac{d^2f}{d^2x} \end{cases}  $

**Task:** Make the variable $g$ move so that it bounces off the barrier $\psi=\delta +\frac{2-\delta }{t T+1}$

where:

$x,g,h$ - state-space variables

$f=-x^2$

$T, \delta$ - positive numbers;

$g_{U_{rep}}=F_{APF}(g)$ - repulsive barrier;

$t$ - time;

I want to use artificial potential barriers that allow ODE variable to avoid obstacles. They are constructed as follows. https://authors.library.caltech.edu/106548/1/2010.09819.pdf

[image]

There is my code:

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -1, xe = 1/2, T = 1/2, \[Delta] = 0.35};

f = -(x[t])^2

(***)

\[Psi]obs = (1 - \[Delta])/(T t + 1) + \[Delta]

krep = 1; dobs = 0.25; \[Rho]0 = 0.25;

\[Rho] = Norm[{G[t] - \[Psi]obs}, 2] - dobs

gUrep = Piecewise[{{krep/\[Rho]^2 (1/\[Rho] - 1/\[Rho]0) G[
       t]/\[Rho], \[Rho] <= \[Rho]0}, {0, \[Rho] > \[Rho]0}}]

Plot[{\[Psi]obs}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]

(***)

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == G[t] + gUrep, G'[t] + G[t] == D[f, x[t]], 
   H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, {x[t], 2}], x[0] == xs, G[0] == 0.5, 
   H[0] == 0}, {x, G, H}, {t, 0, 500}, 
  Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], xe}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 200]

Plot[{Evaluate[G[t] /. sys], \[Psi]obs}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 200]

Plot[{Evaluate[gUrep /. sys]}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 200]
```

*I want to visualize the movement of a system in a steady-state with barriers and also how a variable pushes against these barriers in this system.
I don't know how to correctly express this: vector space visualization, phase-space visualization, etc.*

We may need commands: `ParametricPlot3D` and `ParametricPlot`

Comment: In your example system not approaches barrier.  Do you mean  parametric research to find out some parameters of `gUrep` first?

Comment: @AlexTrounev it is a repulsive barrier that the variable should not approach. in other words, the trajectory that the variable should not jump over.

Comment: With your parametrs `gUrep=0` for `{t,0,500}'. That is the reason to define this function?

Comment: @AlexTrounev $\delta +\frac{1-\delta }{t T+1}$; $G(0)=0$ Alex, I changed $\psi$ to something else, and also changed the initial condition for $G$. Now the barrier has a response. I updated the new version of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can compare  scenario with (green line) and without (red line) barrier as follows

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -1, xe = 1/2, T = 1, \[Delta] = .35};

f = -(x[t])^2;

(***)

\[Psi]obs = (2 - \[Delta])/(T t + 1) + \[Delta];

krep = 1; dobs = 0.05; \[Rho]0 = 0.75;

\[Rho] = Norm[{G[t] - \[Psi]obs}, 2] - dobs;

gUrep = Piecewise[{{krep/\[Rho]^2 (1/\[Rho] - 1/\[Rho]0) G[
        t]/\[Rho], \[Rho] <= \[Rho]0}, {0, \[Rho] > \[Rho]0}}];

Plot[{\[Psi]obs}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]

(***)

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == G[t] + gUrep, G'[t] + G[t] == D[f, x[t]], 
    H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, {x[t], 2}], x[0] == xs, G[0] == 0, 
    H[0] == 0}, {x, G, H}, {t, 0, 500}, 
   Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];


sys0 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == G[t] + 0 gUrep, G'[t] + G[t] == D[f, x[t]], 
    H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, {x[t], 2}], x[0] == xs, G[0] == 0, 
    H[0] == 0}, {x, G, H}, {t, 0, 500}, 
   Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];

ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[{x[t], G[t], H[t]} /. sys], 
  Evaluate[{x[t], G[t], H[t]} /. sys0]}, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "G", "H"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can show part of trajectory where $\rho < \rho_0$ as follows

```
pars = {xs = -1, xe = 1/2, T = 1/2, \[Delta] = 0.35};

f = -(x[t])^2;

(***)

\[Psi]obs = (1 - \[Delta])/(T t + 1) + \[Delta];

krep = 1; dobs = 0.25; \[Rho]0 = 0.25;

\[Rho] = Norm[{G[t] - \[Psi]obs}, 2] - dobs;

gUrep = Piecewise[{{krep/\[Rho]^2 (1/\[Rho] - 1/\[Rho]0) G[
        t]/\[Rho], \[Rho] <= \[Rho]0}, {0., \[Rho] > \[Rho]0}}];

Plot[{\[Psi]obs}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]

(***)

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == G[t] + gUrep, G'[t] + G[t] == D[f, x[t]], 
    H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, {x[t], 2}], x[0] == xs, G[0] == 0.5, 
    H[0] == 0}, {x, G, H}, {t, 0, 500}, 
   Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];

sys0 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == G[t] + 0 gUrep, G'[t] + G[t] == D[f, x[t]], 
    H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, {x[t], 2}], x[0] == xs, G[0] == 0.5, 
    H[0] == 0}, {x, G, H}, {t, 0, 500}, 
   Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];
tms = Table[
   If[First[Evaluate[(\[Rho] - \[Rho]0) /. sys]] < 0, t, Nothing], {t,
     0, 10, .002}];

obst = Graphics3D[
  Table[{Green, Opacity[.25], 
    Sphere[Evaluate[{x[t], G[t], H[t]} /. sys], .05]}, {t, tms}]];

Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate[{x[t], G[t], H[t]} /. sys]}, {t, 0, 
   50}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "G", "H"}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"], obst]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: can we add another one to this figure, but replace $g$ to \psi ?

Comment: Do you mean replace `G` with `\[Psi]obs`? Then what is the sense of this plot?

Comment: Yes. The meaning of the graph is as follows: $\psi$ sets the trajectory to which the variable $G$ cannot go. I would like to clearly see how this happens. In the articles where I got this from, they build obstacle avoidance on the plane. I would like to get something similar.

Comment: In such a setting, there really is not much sense, but I want to somehow visualize the work of the system, how its phase space changes (when I add a barrier) and how the system moves in this space. But I don't know of any other form of visualization of this. 

For example: https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2020/6523158.pdf [p. 11-16]