# Multidimensional obstacle avoidance in ODE. Part II

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, control-systems

[Multidimensional obstacle avoidance in ODE (Visualization)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246413/multidimensional-obstacle-avoidance-in-ode-visualization)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146255/multidimensional-obstacle-avoidance-in-ode

For some time, I studied this question more closely and came to the conclusion that it is best to assign its own constraint for each selected coordinate. Here are the results.

I choose those system of ODE:

$F=\begin{cases} \dot{x}=g_x+\frac{d(U_{rep_1})}{dx} \\  \dot{g_x}=-g_x+\frac{df}{dx} \\ \dot{y}=g_y+\frac{d(U_{rep_2})}{dy} \\ \dot{g_y}=-g_y+\frac{df}{dy} \end{cases}$

where $x,y,g_x,g_y$ - variables;

$f=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$

$U_{rep_1}=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\rho_1}-\frac{1}{\rho_0})^2, & \mbox{if } \rho_1<=\rho_0\mbox{} \\ 0, & \mbox{if } \rho_1>\rho_0\mbox{} \end{cases}$

$U_{rep_2}=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\rho_2}-\frac{1}{\rho_0})^2, & \mbox{if } \rho_2<=\rho_0\mbox{} \\ 0, & \mbox{if } \rho_2>\rho_0\mbox{} \end{cases}$

$\rho_1=\sqrt{(x-\psi_1)^2}-d_{obs}$

$\rho_2=\sqrt{(y-\psi_2)^2}-d_{obs}$

$\psi_1=\delta +2 e^{-t T}$

$\psi_2=\delta +\frac{1}{2.2}e^{-t T}$

$\rho_0 = 0.15, T = 0.5, \delta = 0.35,d_{obs}=0.1$

The figure below shows the results of numerical simulations from Mathematica. It can be seen that the selected variables cannot cross the selected barrier.

[image]

The following is interesting. When a variable touches the barrier, it kind of "sticks" to it, holds on for a while, and then "unsticks". At this time, $\frac{d(U_{rep_1})}{dx}$ and $\frac{d(U_{rep_2})}{dy}$ is not zero.

[image]

**In general, I ask for help with this task** - *how to quickly "detach" the variable from the barrier? Are there any tricks? Maybe experts in differential equations and dynamical systems can help. I will be glad to help.*

There is my code:

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

f = Exp[-((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)]

X = {x[t], y[t]}

xgoal = {0, 0}

Uatt = 1/2 Sqrt[(X - xgoal).(X - xgoal)]^2

Urep1 = Piecewise[{{(krep/
       2 (1/\[Rho]1 - 
         1/\[Rho]0)^2), \[Rho]1 <= \[Rho]0}, {0, \[Rho]1 > \[Rho]0}}]


obs1 = 2 Exp[-1 T t] + \[Delta]

dobs1 = 0.1

\[Rho]1 = Sqrt[{x[t] - obs1}.{x[t] - obs1}] - dobs1

Urep2 = Piecewise[{{(krep/
       2 (1/\[Rho]2 - 
         1/\[Rho]0)^2), \[Rho]2 <= \[Rho]0}, {0, \[Rho]2 > \[Rho]0}}]


obs2 = 1/2.2 Exp[-1 T t] + \[Delta]

dobs2 = 0.1

\[Rho]2 = Sqrt[{y[t] - obs2}.{y[t] - obs2}] - dobs2

krep = 1; \[Rho]0 = 0.15; T = 1/2; \[Delta] = 0.35;

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Gx[t] - (D[Urep1, x[t]]), 
   Gx'[t] + Gx[t] == D[f, x[t]], y'[t] == Gy[t] - (D[Urep2, y[t]]), 
   Gy'[t] + Gy[t] == D[f, y[t]], x[0] == 1.25, y[0] == 1/2, 
   Gx[0] == 0.255, Gy[0] == 0.45}, {x, y, Gx, Gy}, {t, 0, 500}, 
  Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], Evaluate[y[t] /. sys], obs1, obs2}, {t, 
  0, 20}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 200]

Plot[{Evaluate[Gx[t] /. sys], obs1, Evaluate[Gy[t] /. sys], obs2}, {t,
   0, 50}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 200]

Plot[{Evaluate[D[Urep1, x[t]] /. sys], 
  Evaluate[D[Urep2, y[t]] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 200]

Plot[{Evaluate[\[Rho]1 /. sys], dobs1, Evaluate[\[Rho]2 /. sys], 
  dobs2, \[Rho]0, 0}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

Comment: By trial and error, I see that this change seems to do what you want. `c = 1.2;
\[Rho]1 = Sqrt[{x[t] - c obs1} . {x[t] - c obs1}] - dobs1;
\[Rho]2 = Sqrt[{y[t] - c obs2} . {y[t] - c obs2}] - dobs2;`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This method has limited application. If the coefficient $c$ is too high, the system stops responding to repulsive barriers.  It happened with $c>=2$.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This is a tricky ploy. The coefficient $c$ simply "pushes" the repulsive barrier to the upper right half-plane. No, such a solution will not work.

Comment: We can use `WhenEvent` to force system to reflect from obstacle.

Comment: @AlexTrounev it will be difficult to transfer this to Simulink. I would like to figure out how to quickly make the $\frac{d(U_{rep_1})}{dx}$ and $\frac{d(U_{rep_2})}{dy}$ tozero.equal to zero again after colliding with the barrier ...

Comment: Is Simulink some restriction to this problem? Can you formulate your problem so that we understand what parameters and functions we can use to solve it? Can we use `If[]`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev no, no problem, I guess. It just seems to me that one more differential equation needs to be included in the system. Those. there must be something else and preferably continuous ... hmm ... yes, we need to come up with a continuous way to reduce the gradient after colliding with a barrier

Comment: @AlexTrounev we can use any functions that solve the problem, including `If[]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I also discovered that the Gaussian function can be used as a repulsive barrier, but has not yet solved the problem with "sticking" to the barrier.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I also discovered that the Gaussian function can be used as a repulsive barrier, but has not yet solved the problem with "sticking" to the barrier.